# Expression Blend 4 accidently deleted App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

Im new to Expression and by accident I deleted the App.xaml file. I think this is an important file and I cannot workout how to create an equivalent.

Please help,

Andy

Comment: Aren't you using a source control repository? Also can't you create a new project and reuse the file from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new project and copy that one.

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Unless you had Application Resources defined, then you may be in trouble.

Might be a good argument for Source Control.

Comment: Yeah - going to use scm soon! So i tried that - and im getting : Partial Declarations of 'app' must not specify different base classes....

Comment: I would recommend git and a website like http://github.com (if you need offline backup)

Comment: Are you also bringing the App.xaml.cs file into the project

Comment: Yea - currently I have the App.xaml which looks like what you pasted but I changed x:Class to "MyApp.App" and the startup URI to be "MainWindow.xaml" and then in the code for the App.xaml.cs file I have [code]public partial class App : Window
 {
  public App()
  {
   this.InitializeComponent();
   
   // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
  }
 }[/code] and it is complaining about the public partial class line

Comment: You need to give 


public partial class App : Application 

instead of 


partial class App : Window

The Application class is defined in System.Windows namespace so if you wish you can fully qualify it as below



public partial class App : System.Windows.Application

Comment: ok done that thanks, now it says Program "<path to exe"> does not have a static main method suitable for an entry point. What is it looking for!?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Same thing happened with me. I had to leave out `InitializeComponent()` because it said it was ambiguous. To answer your question, you have to set the startup app. Right-click your project name in Solution Explorer > Properties > Set Startup object to YourProject.App.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy You actually have to replace `public App() {}` with a `Main` function.  I'll post in an answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Page and call it `App.xaml`.

Replace its markup as benPearce indicated with this:

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Replace "Test" above with your namespace and "Window1" with the name of the first page you want shown in your project.

Replace the class in the App.xaml.cs code-behind with this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        YourNamespace.App app = new YourNamespace.App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Ensure that your Project Properties are set in the "Application" area such that your startup object is `YourNamespace.App`.

Perform a build and you shouldn't get anymore errors related to 'App'.